# Running java application written using Eclipse from command prompt

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I have a java application that I created using Eclipse 3.7 and also run from this IDE.
Now I want to run it from command prompt. How should I go for it?

Do i have to create jar file to do this ?

And I am also setting some system properties in run configurations, so also specify how to pass them while running it frm command prompt.

Comment: Try looking at the man page for java -- http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/java/ You'll be especially interested in the `-D` option for setting system properties.

Comment: @RohitElayathu - If you are having problem, than mention the problem you faced

Answer (score 1):

There are many tutorial. here is the general process.

1. Compile all classes, you may use Eclipse or `javac`
2. You do not need to Jar it up. Go to your package root. And run it as

   ```
    java -cp .:path/to/requires/jars:/some/more/jar FullyQualifiedMainClassNameWithoutExtension param1 param2
   ```
3. If you have properties to be feed into you may have that at package root and use `ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream("/filename.properties")`
4. If you look into `args` of your `main(String[] args)` you will find `param1`, `param2` there.

Refer

1. http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~parrt/course/601/lectures/java.tools.html
2. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html

Note:

- If you have multiple Jars use wldcard to include your Jars. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html
- the classpath delimiter is `:` for Unix, and `;` for Windows

---

This tutorial is the best example of spoon feeding. But, whatever makes you go [Compile and run Java program in package from command line](http://shivasoft.in/blog/java/compile-and-run-java-program-in-package-from-command-line/)

Comment: -but i hav lots of jars. I dont want to type in all the jars.

Comment: Java6+ use wild card see here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Answer (score 0):

Switch to the "debug" perspective and run your program in Eclipse.
Write-click the process (even after it terminates) in the "debug" window and select "properties".
In the properties dialog you see the entire command line used by eclipse. You can copy and paste it in a shell to execute it.
You might want to change the command from "javaw" to "java". Up to you.